# Is there a way to avoid using npm start using WebServers?

Tags: node.js, apache, nginx, xampp

I'm learning about NodeJS, but, the first thing that i noticed is that i need to do a NPM RUN App everytime something is modified in the code.

I read about a package in Node to automatically do it. But i wonder if there is something more simpler

Is there a way to use it like a Laravel app?
Something like, creating a folder in the htdocs and just save it and refresh the webpage to see the changes?

Comment: Nodemon is what you’re looking for, you install it on your dev machine globally. (npm install -g nodemon) and your dev start command becomes “nodemon index.js” or whatever your entry file is. This will look for changes and restart your node server. Then when you reload your page it will show these changes

Comment: Ok i get it, but, basically what Nodemon does is execute the "npm run" in the background every time you save. There is no way that i just leave my project in the htdocs (apache) and refresh to see the changes? Do you know why? something need to be compile obligatorily with node in order to work? Thank you for the Nodemon